# How to insert/delete items to/from an underlying `csv` file in `razor`

Tags: c#, html, razor-pages

I am a beginner in `html` and `razor` design and coding. I am trying to implement a simple `cshtml`-based page that handles the display and the management of some items stored in a `csv` file. I have managed to put in place the 'insert' action of new items but I am not sure how to handle the opposite 'delete' action.

The page provides a form to carry out the 'insert' action and displays the `csv` file under the form of a table. Each row of the table is combined with a 'delete' button to remove the designated line. Here is my code based on a simplified data model (product-price).

```
@{
    string dataFile = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/data.csv");
}

@{
    string display = null;
    Array dataArray = null;
    char[] delim = { ',' };

    if (File.Exists(dataFile))
    {
        dataArray = File.ReadAllLines(dataFile);
        if (dataArray == null)
        {
            display = "File is empty.";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        display = "File does not exist.";
    }
}

@{
    string insert = null;
    if (IsPost)
    {
        string product = Request["Product"];
        string price = Request["Price"];
        if (product == null || product == ""
            || price == null || price == "")
        {
            insert = "Incomplete product price input.";
        }
        else
        {
            string dataLine = product + "," + price + Environment.NewLine;
            File.AppendAllText(@dataFile, dataLine);
            insert = "Product price saved.";
        }
    }
}

<section>
    <form id="insert" method="post">
        <div>
            <label style="font-size:10px">
                Product:
                <input id="Product" name="Product" type="text" style="font-size:10px; width:150px;"/>
                <text>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;</text>
                Price:
                <input id="Price" name="Price" type="number" step="0.01" style="font-size:10px; width:50px;"/>
            </label>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </div>
        <div>
            @if (insert != null)
            {
                <p>@insert</p>
            }
        </div>
    </form>
</section>

<section>
    <table style="width:40%;
        font-size:10px;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width:60%;">Product</th>
                <th style="width:20%;">Price</th>
                <th style="width:20%;">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @display
            @if (display == null)
            {
                foreach (string dataRow in dataArray)
                {
                    <tr>
                        @foreach (string dataItem in dataRow.Split(delim))
                        {
                            <td>@dataItem</td>
                        }
                        <td>
                            <form id="remove" method="post" />
                            <button form="remove" type="submit" 
                                style="font-size:8px; padding:2px; text-align:center;">
                                Delete
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</section>
```

I do not really know how to proceed from there to link the 'remove' button to the re-writing of the underlying `csv` file.

As an additional question, I am trying to figure out how I could factorise this code (I would like to use the same insert/delete/table skeleton on different pages without having to re-write the same thing) with the simple difference that I would need to target different underlying `csv` files for each different page.

Comment: From the code you posted, it looks like you are using the very old ASP.NET Web Pages framework, not Razor Pages. Web Pages is more or less obsolete.  Also, using a CSV as a data source is not recommended because it doesn't support concurrency. I suggest learning Razor Pages and using a database instead: https://www.learnrazorpages.com

Comment: Thank you for the comment @Mike Brind. Do you know what the minimal .NET framework and Visual Studio version to use to have razor? I am on Windows 10.

Comment: Minimal version of .NET Core with Razor Pages support is 3.0, but the SDK is a free download and Visual Studio Code is also free (as is VS Community Edition) so I don't know why you wouldn't use the latest versions of each.